# Open UIPickerView by clicking on an entry in the app's preferences - How to?

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I am wondering how and whether the UIPickerView can be opened due to the user's pushing of an entry in the app's preference pane.

Thank you !

- I am speaking about iPhone Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean your app's section in the iPhone's built-in Settings app, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks!

Comment: I simply wanted to take or choose a picture after pushing a button in the prefs and assign it as background for my app.

Comment: So you were not talking about UIPickerView but UIImagePickerController, which is a totally different thing. The answer is still the same though, it's not possible.