# Opening the Settings app from another app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, application-settings, appsettings

Okay, I know that there are many question about it, but they are all from many time ago.

So. I know that it is possible because the Map app does it.

In the Map app if I turn off the localization for this app, it send me a message, and if I press okay, the "Settings App" will be open.
And my question is, how is this possible?
How can I open the "Setting app" from my own app?

Basically I need to do the same thing, if the user turn off the location for my app, then I'll show him a message saying something that will open the "Setting app"

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377102/how-do-i-open-the-settings-application-from-my-application/24570751#24570751

Comment: You can open settings app programmatically in iOS8(but not in lower versions of iOS).code below in answers.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

As mentioned by [Karan Dua](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24952919/418715) this is [now possible in iOS8](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html) using `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` see [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring).

**Example:**

**Swift 4.2**

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
```

*In Swift 3:*

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

*In Swift 2:*

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

*In Objective-C*

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

**Prior to iOS 8:**

You can not. As you said this has been covered many times and that pop up asking you to turn on location services is supplied by Apple and not by the App itself. That is why it is able to the open the settings application.

Here are a few related questions & articles:

[is it possible to open Settings App using openURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090373/is-it-possible-to-open-settings-app-using-openurl)

[Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/programmatically-opening-the-settings-app-iphone)

[How can I open the Settings app when the user presses a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092162/how-can-i-open-the-settings-app-when-the-user-presses-a-button)

[iPhone: Opening Application Preferences Panel From App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113391/iphone-opening-application-preferences-panel-from-app)

[Open UIPickerView by clicking on an entry in the app's preferences - How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127769/open-uipickerview-by-clicking-on-an-entry-in-the-apps-preferences-how-to)

[Open the Settings app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942974/open-settings-app)

[iOS: You’re Doing Settings Wrong](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-taking-the-user-to-settings/)

Comment: If you need a more authoritative answer, you might try asking on the Apple Developer forums <http://developer.apple.com/devforums/> or filing a bug at <http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/> — if it's a known issue it should come back as "behaves correctly" or a duplicate of the original bug.

Comment: [Not possible is rarely true in the field of programming.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587370/how-some-apps-can-open-setting-app-programmatically-within-their-app#14587480)

Comment: I agree if you are willing to bend/break the rules.

Comment: This is now possible in iOS 8 using [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]

Comment: @Joe This solution is not working for iOS 10 . I am working on Xcode 8, swift 3. Any alternate solution please?

Comment: @joe i have worked in iOS 10. its not Works. if any other solution please update your answer.

Comment: I think, they still work with Extensions. Ex app is `Magic Launcher` in Appstore.

Comment: in swift 3 - UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)

Comment: Be wary of using this method. I used it and a few months later my app got rejected with the following message from Apple:

Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.

Comment: @Nick Kirsten did you mean this answer or the answer bellow ?, I can't see any "prefs:root" phrase in the current answer. Also, what did you do instead ?

Comment: `openSettingsURLString` is a public API, see documentation: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring

Answer (score 134):

From [@Yatheeshaless](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2024072/yatheesha)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570712/2789144):

You can open settings app programmatically in iOS8, but not in earlier versions of iOS.

**Swift:**

```
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
```

**Swift 4:**

```
if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) as URL? {
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

**Swift 4.2 (BETA):**

```
if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) as URL? {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

**Objective-C:**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Comment: This appears to open your app's section of the Settings app. Users will have to hit Back a few times to see the main screen of Settings.

Comment: Small correction.. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];`

Comment: @Paito 
The above line is directing to **app private settings**. Is there any way to direct to **privacy** section of the device settings? Please comment if you know. This redirection is possible, as I found it in maps app where it directs to location settings in privacy section.

Comment: Not sure if it's possible, Apple apps often do things that we can't by using private APIs, the Google Maps app just goes to the App Settings not Location Services.

Comment: Small Swift correction:     UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)

Comment: @PavanKotesh- Yes but the app settings will have what you need permission for, in my case i needed access to contacts, which do appear in app settings with above code.

Answer (score 60):

**YES!!** you can launch Device Settings screen, I have **tested on iOS 9.2**

**Step 1.** we need to add URL schemes

Go to Project settings --> Info --> URL Types --> Add New URL Schemes

[image]

**Step 2.** Launch Settings programmatically Thanks to [@davidcann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2054/davidcann)

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Also we can launch sub-screens like Music, Location etc. as well by just using proper name

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=MUSIC"]];
```

See this full name list [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme?rq=1) shared by Henri Normak

---

**Update:**

**As per the comment everyone wants to know what happens after this change to my application submission status?**

So `YES!! I got successful update submission and application is available on store without any complain.`

Just to confirm,
I Just downloaded this morning and disabled Location services, and then started the app, which asked me for location permission and then my alert popup was there to send me on settings -> location services page --> Enabled --> That's it!!

***[![NOTICE:
Your app might be rejected ... even if it's approved it can be rejected in future version if you use this method...][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o4xu.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o4xu.jpg)***

Comment: Thanks, works for me, on iOS 6 and 7, too. Did you try to get it through Apple's review process yet?

Comment: @Flo I will let you know, because presently I have pushed for beta testing.

Comment: Hey @RDC, have you got any news about the review of your app?

Comment: @RDC did your app pass the App Review process?

Comment: iOS 9.3. Worked like a charm. I even see "Back to [my app name]" inside the settings app. Surely, this is supported because I see plenty of other apps that do this kind of thing!

Comment: I am using that and it failed the submission to app store? Anyone else had the same issue or a work around it?

Comment: @RDC Did Apple approved the build with "prefs" private APIs?

Comment: @msg   **YES!! The application has been approved** and available on store.

Comment: From the feedbacks in 2012, using the code 'prefs:' to be rejected, but from this feedback as now in 2016, he says 'approved', Then, hope he be right.

Comment: I think, they still work with Extensions. Ex app is `Magic Launcher` in Appstore.

Comment: On iOS 10, the new url is not "prefs:root=...." but "App-Prefs:root=...".

Comment: Your app might be rejected ... even if it's approved it can be rejected in future version if you use this method...

Comment: Do not do step 1. That is where you define the custom URL schemes that open your own app.

Answer (score 40):

Seems like you can use the `prefs:<area>` URL to open the settings and go to specific areas. Apple could change these and break your app so always check if you can open them first.

From this [article](https://www.macstories.net/ios/a-comprehensive-guide-to-all-120-settings-urls-supported-by-ios-and-ipados-13-1/) they have listed some of them for iOS 13.1:

**Settings URLs**

**iCloud**

- iCloud: `prefs:root=CASTLE`
- iCloud Backup: `prefs:root=CASTLE&path=BACKUP`

**Wireless Radios**

- Wi-Fi: `prefs:root=WIFI`
- Bluetooth: `prefs:root=Bluetooth`
- Cellular: `prefs:root=MOBILE_DATA_SETTINGS_ID`

**Personal Hotspot**

- Personal Hotspot: `prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING`
- Personal Hotspot ⇾ Family Sharing: `prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING&path=Family%20Sharing`
- Personal Hotspot ⇾ Wi-Fi Password: `prefs:root=INTERNET_TETHERING&path=Wi-Fi%20Password`

**VPN**

- VPN: `prefs:root=General&path=VPN`

**Notifications**

- Notifications: `prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID`
- Notifications ⇾ Siri Suggestions: `prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=Siri%20Suggestions`

**Sounds**

- Sounds: `prefs:root=Sounds`
- Ringtone: `prefs:root=Sounds&path=Ringtone`

**Do Not Disturb**

- Do Not Disturb: `prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB`
- Do Not Disturb ⇾ Allow Calls From: `prefs:root=DO_NOT_DISTURB&path=Allow%20Calls%20From`

**Screen Time**

- Screen Time: `prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME`
- Screen Time ⇾ Downtime: `prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=DOWNTIME`
- Screen Time ⇾ App Limits: `prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=APP_LIMITS`
- Screen Time ⇾ Always Allowed: `prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=ALWAYS_ALLOWED`

**General**

- General: `prefs:root=General`
- General ⇾ About: `prefs:root=General&path=About`
- General ⇾ Software Update: `prefs:root=General&path=SOFTWARE_UPDATE_LINK`
- General ⇾ CarPlay: `prefs:root=General&path=CARPLAY`
- General ⇾ Background App Refresh: `prefs:root=General&path=AUTO_CONTENT_DOWNLOAD`
- General ⇾ Multitasking (iPad-only): `prefs:root=General&path=MULTITASKING`
- General ⇾ Date & Time: `prefs:root=General&path=DATE_AND_TIME`
- General ⇾ Keyboard: `prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard`
- General ⇾ Keyboard ⇾ Keyboards: `prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/KEYBOARDS`
- General ⇾ Keyboard ⇾ Hardware Keyboard: `prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/Hardware%20Keyboard`
- General ⇾ Keyboard ⇾ Text Replacement: `prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/USER_DICTIONARY`
- General ⇾ Keyboard ⇾ One Handed Keyboard: `prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard/ReachableKeyboard`
- General ⇾ Language & Region: `prefs:root=General&path=INTERNATIONAL`
- General ⇾ Dictionary: `prefs:root=General&path=DICTIONARY`
- General ⇾ Profiles: `prefs:root=General&path=ManagedConfigurationList`
- General ⇾ Reset: `prefs:root=General&path=Reset`

**Control Center**

- Control Center: `prefs:root=ControlCenter`
- Control Center ⇾ Customize Controls: `prefs:root=ControlCenter&path=CUSTOMIZE_CONTROLS`

**Display**

- Display: `prefs:root=DISPLAY`
- Display ⇾ Auto Lock: `prefs:root=DISPLAY&path=AUTOLOCK`
- Display ⇾ Text Size: `prefs:root=DISPLAY&path=TEXT_SIZE`

**Accessibility**

- Accessibility: `prefs:root=ACCESSIBILITY`

**Wallpaper**

- Wallpaper: `prefs:root=Wallpaper`

**Siri**

- Siri: `prefs:root=SIRI`

**Apple Pencil**

- Apple Pencil (iPad-only): `prefs:root=Pencil`

**Face ID**

- Face ID: `prefs:root=PASSCODE`

**Emergency SOS**

- Emergency SOS: `prefs:root=EMERGENCY_SOS`

**Battery**

- Battery: `prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE`
- Battery ⇾ Battery Health (iPhone-only): `prefs:root=BATTERY_USAGE&path=BATTERY_HEALTH`

**Privacy**

- Privacy: `prefs:root=Privacy`
- Privacy ⇾ Location Services: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION`
- Privacy ⇾ Contacts: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=CONTACTS`
- Privacy ⇾ Calendars: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=CALENDARS`
- Privacy ⇾ Reminders: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=REMINDERS`
- Privacy ⇾ Photos: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=PHOTOS`
- Privacy ⇾ Microphone: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=MICROPHONE`
- Privacy ⇾ Speech Recognition: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=SPEECH_RECOGNITION`
- Privacy ⇾ Camera: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=CAMERA`
- Privacy ⇾ Motion: `prefs:root=Privacy&path=MOTION\`

**App Store**

- App Store: `prefs:root=STORE`
- App Store ⇾ App Downloads: `prefs:root=STORE&path=App%20Downloads`
- App Store ⇾ Video Autoplay: `prefs:root=STORE&path=Video%20Autoplay`

**Wallet**

- Wallet: `prefs:root=PASSBOOK`

**Passwords & Accounts**

- Passwords & Accounts: `prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS`
- Passwords & Accounts ⇾ Fetch New Data: `prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS&path=FETCH_NEW_DATA`
- Passwords & Accounts ⇾ Add Account: `prefs:root=ACCOUNTS_AND_PASSWORDS&path=ADD_ACCOUNT`

**Mail**

- Mail: `prefs:root=MAIL`
- Mail ⇾ Preview: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Preview`
- Mail ⇾ Swipe Options: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Swipe%20Options`
- Mail ⇾ Notifications: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=NOTIFICATIONS`
- Mail ⇾ Blocked: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Blocked`
- Mail ⇾ Muted Thread Action: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Muted%20Thread%20Action`
- Mail ⇾ Blocked Sender Options: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Blocked%20Sender%20Options`
- Mail ⇾ Mark Addresses: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Mark%20Addresses`
- Mail ⇾ Increase Quote Level: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Increase%20Quote%20Level`
- Mail ⇾ Include Attachments with Replies: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Include%20Attachments%20with%20Replies`
- Mail ⇾ Signature: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Signature`
- Mail ⇾ Default Account: `prefs:root=MAIL&path=Default%20Account`

**Contacts**

- Contacts: `prefs:root=CONTACTS`

**Calendar**

- Calendar: `prefs:root=CALENDAR`
- Calendar ⇾ Alternate Calendars: `prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Alternate%20Calendars`
- Calendar ⇾ Sync: `prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Sync`
- Calendar ⇾ Default Alert Times: `prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Default%20Alert%20Times`
- Calendar ⇾ Default Calendar: `prefs:root=CALENDAR&path=Default%20Calendar`

**Notes**

- Notes: `prefs:root=NOTES`
- Notes ⇾ Default Account: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Default%20Account`
- Notes ⇾ Password: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Password`
- Notes ⇾ Sort Notes By: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Sort%20Notes%20By`
- Notes ⇾ New Notes Start With: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=New%20Notes%20Start%20With`
- Notes ⇾ Sort Checked Items: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Sort%20Checked%20Items`
- Notes ⇾ Lines & Grids: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Lines%20%26%20Grids`
- Notes ⇾ Access Notes from Lock Screen: `prefs:root=NOTES&path=Access%20Notes%20from%20Lock%20Screen`

**Reminders**

- Reminders: `prefs:root=REMINDERS`
- Reminders ⇾ Default List: `prefs:root=REMINDERS&path=DEFAULT_LIST`

**Voice Memos**

- Voice Memos: `prefs:root=VOICE_MEMOS`

**Phone**

- Phone: `prefs:root=Phone`

**Messages**

- Messages: `prefs:root=MESSAGES`

**FaceTime**

- FaceTime: `prefs:root=FACETIME`

**Maps**

- Maps: `prefs:root=MAPS`
- Maps ⇾ Driving & Navigation: `prefs:root=MAPS&path=Driving%20%26%20Navigation`
- Maps ⇾ Transit: `prefs:root=MAPS&path=Transit`

**Compass**

- Compass: `prefs:root=COMPASS`

**Measure**

- Measure: `prefs:root=MEASURE`

**Safari**

- Safari: `prefs:root=SAFARI`
- Safari ⇾ Content Blockers: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Content%20Blockers`
- Safari ⇾ Downloads: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=DOWNLOADS`
- Safari ⇾ Close Tabs: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Close%20Tabs`
- Safari ⇾ Clear History and Data: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=CLEAR_HISTORY_AND_DATA`
- Safari ⇾ Page Zoom: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Page%20Zoom`
- Safari ⇾ Request Desktop Website: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Request%20Desktop%20Website`
- Safari ⇾ Reader: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Reader`
- Safari ⇾ Camera: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Camera`
- Safari ⇾ Microphone: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Microphone`
- Safari ⇾ Location: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=Location`
- Safari ⇾ Advanced: `prefs:root=SAFARI&path=ADVANCED`

**News**

- News: `prefs:root=NEWS`

**Health**

- Health: `prefs:root=HEALTH`

**Shortcuts**

- Shortcuts: `prefs:root=SHORTCUTS`

**Music**

- Music: `prefs:root=MUSIC`
- Music ⇾ Cellular Data: `prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:CellularData`
- Music ⇾ Optimize Storage: `prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:OptimizeStorage`
- Music ⇾ EQ: `prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:EQ`
- Music ⇾ Volume Limit: `prefs:root=MUSIC&path=com.apple.Music:VolumeLimit`

**TV**

- Settings ⇾ TV: `prefs:root=TVAPP`

**Photos**

- Photos: `prefs:root=Photos`

**Camera**

- Camera: `prefs:root=CAMERA`
- Camera ⇾ Record Video: `prefs:root=CAMERA&path=Record%20Video`
- Camera ⇾ Record Slo-mo: `prefs:root=CAMERA&path=Record%20Slo-mo`

**Books**

- Books: `prefs:root=IBOOKS`

**Game Center**

- Game Center: `prefs:root=GAMECENTER`

Comment: this is not working for iOS 14 ..always showing settings instead of path mentioned. any workaround ?

Comment: yes, i have also same issue with iOS 14 but in my case it is resolved when i remove root prefix.
for example instead of "prefs:root=Privacy&path=LOCATION" i have ued "App-prefs:Privacy&path=LOCATION" and it works in iOS 14.

Comment: Does Apple no longer reject the app if we use such configurations?

Comment: @letsbondiway did you find an answer to this? I also need to know if they still reject apps that do this (since I can find examples of current apps in App Store that clearly do it).

Answer (score 17):

<strike>You can use this on iOS 5.0 and later:</strike> This no longer works.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

Comment: Son of a gun, that actually works! I can't find any documentation reference to this. Do you have one? What the behavior of this code under iOS4? Other than failure, what happens? Nothing?

Comment: @MarkGranoff No, it seems to be technically undocumented, but it's not as bad as a normal undocumented API, since it's just a URL Scheme.  You can check for it with canOpenURL: first.  Also, there's a thread about it here: https://devforums.apple.com/message/543818

Comment: Right! Excellent points. That DevForum thread suggested that undocumented == private API, which means: don't use it (until it's documented. :-)

Comment: You can get to different areas in settings according to [this article](http://forums.tipb.com/iphone-4s-forum/223832-use-siri-access-system-preferences.html).  For example this URL will take you to Bluetooth settings `prefs:root=General&path=Bluetooth `

Comment: I got an application rejected for using private API because I was opening the url: @"prefs:root=Brightness". Usually, un-documented means private.

Comment: Apple has stated that this wasn't a public API, and is no longer supported.  There is a bug filed on this issue, number 11253669.

Comment: I just saw that this works in Strava app. Turn off Bluetooth & then turn it on in app. Then it asks to got to settings app & it goes directly to Bluetooth settings. This is for iOS5.1. Is there a way to find out what scheme they are using?

Comment: @Ants see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682164/iphone-open-settings-from-my-application-ios-6

Answer (score 14):

**iOS 10 update**

Apple changed the method to open async on the main thread. However, from now it is only possible to open the app settings in native settings.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url options:@{} completionHandler:nil];`

**iOS 9 update**

It is now possible to go directly to sub-settings menu. However, a URL scheme has to be created. It can be done using two ways:

1. XCode - You will find it in Target, Info, URL Scheme. Then, just type prefs.
2. Directly adding to *-Info.plist. Add the following:
   `<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
   <array>
       <dict>
           <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
           <string>Editor</string>
           <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
           <array>
               <string>prefs</string>
           </array>
       </dict>
   </array>`

Then the code:

Swift

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard")!)`

Objective-c

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Keyboard"]];`

Comment: I tried the iOS 10.x solution, and it didn't work for me - nothing happens.

Comment: @MarkPeters, did you figure out a way yet? It could be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't. I still don't know if it is an iOS bug or if Apple just removed the feature.

Comment: I think, they still work with Extensions. Ex app is `Magic Launcher` in Appstore.

Comment: Do not perform step 2. `CFBundleURLTypes` is where you define the custom URL schemes used to open your own app.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3 / iOS 10+ this now looks like

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: .none)
}
```

Comment: how to get to notification screen?

because if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=io.artup.artup") {
     if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: .none)
     }
    }


but i went to notification in iPhone 6 not in iPhone 7 plus?

Comment: This will get your app rejected. They put it under use of private API.

Comment: I have got rejected my app, using this "App-Prefs:root"

Comment: Just emphasize what others mentioned here, don't use this method, it'll get your app rejected. Repeatedly submitting app with such will get your developer account closed.

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3 all I needed is this (here for example redirect to my app notifications):

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID&path=your app bundleID") {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, completionHandler: .none)
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
}
```

Source: [phynet gist](https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4).

This worked with me only when settings is in background. It will redirect you to your app notification settings but if settings wasn't running in the background it will just redirect you to notification settings in general.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3:

```
guard let url = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {return}
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
  UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
} else {
  // Fallback on earlier versions
  UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` this will only work if you have previously allowed for any permission. For example Location, Photo, Contact, Push notification access. So if you have not such permission(s) from the user:

If **iOS 10 or above**,

It will open the Settings but then crash it. The reason, there's nothing in settings for your app.

Below code will open your application settings inside the iOS Setting.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

Due to device unavailability, I couldn't check this on iOS < 10.

Also, I could find below code from some gist and it works fine on iOS 10 as well. But I am not sure if this will approve by Apple review team or not.

https://gist.github.com/johnny77221/bcaa5384a242b64bfd0b8a715f48e69f

Answer (score 3):

As `openURL(_:)` is deprecated after iOS 10.0, use `open(_:options:completionHandler:)` instead.

```
if let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)  {
        UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, options: [:]) { completed in
             if !completed {
                 print("Failed opening")
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code for it.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Tested with iOS 10. Working

```
NSArray* urlStrings = @[@"prefs:root=WIFI", @"App-Prefs:root=WIFI"];
for(NSString* urlString in urlStrings){
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    break;
}
}
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: This will get your app rejected. Just had it happen to me.

Comment: Is that so, But this line of code will directly take you to the desired location

Comment: Yes it will get you there. I'm not saying it doesn't work, I'm just pointing out that it will get you rejected during app review. 
"prefs:root" is a private url scheme according to what the review team told us.
(You might get lucky and they don't notice for a while, we had the feature in for a while and passed several reviews before the reviewer noticed it)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I would try something else, But right now i am stucked in VPN connectivity, Finding a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4.0**

> 'openURL' was deprecated in iOS 10.0: Please use
>   openURL:options:completionHandler: instead

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL.init(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)! , options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

***Swift 4***

I prefer to open setting in a safer way,

```
if let settingUrl = URL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {

    UIApplication.shared.open(settingUrl)
}
else {
    print("Setting URL invalid")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 16, you can use [openSettingsURLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring/)

```swift
if let url = URL(string: UIApplication. openSettingsURLString) {
    await UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 
You can use following function to open Settings App with Bluetooth Page

```
func openSettingsApp(){
    if let settings = NSURL(string: "prefs:root=Bluetooth") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settings)
    }
}
```

Again this would not open the App's Settings. This would open settings app with Bluetooth as this is deep linking to bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

To add to accepted answer: (from apple developer documentation) "When you open the URL built from this string (openSettingsURLString), the system launches the Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any." So, if you want to open settings for your app, create your own Settings.bundle.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your class,

```
 public class func showSettingsAlert(title:String,message:String,onVC viewController:UIViewController,onCancel:(()->())?){
            YourClass.show2ButtonsAlert(onVC: viewController, title: title, message: message, button1Title: "Settings", button2Title: "Cancel", onButton1Click: {
                if let settingsURL = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString){
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(settingsURL)
                }
                }, onButton2Click: {
                    onCancel?()
            })
        }

 public class func show2ButtonsAlert(onVC viewController:UIViewController,title:String,message:String,button1Title:String,button2Title:String,onButton1Click:(()->())?,onButton2Click:(()->())?){
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: button1Title, style:.Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                    onButton1Click?()
                }))

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: button2Title, style:.Default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                    onButton2Click?()
                }))

                viewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Call like this,

```
YourClass.showSettingsAlert("App would like to access camera", message: "App would like to access camera desc", onVC: fromViewController, onCancel: {
  print("canceled")
})
```