# programmatically READ iPhone settings

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to programmatically READ iPhone settings such as...

- Enable 3G - YES/NO
- Vibrate - ON/OFF
- Message Alert - ON/OFF
- etc.

Can anyone provide a solution?

Comment: All settings are sandboxed. You can only read yours.

Comment: Why would your application need to know if vibration is on or off?  If 3G is enable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain you cannot: see [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Because apple is not providing the API to access the iPhone settings app. But you can keep a bundle setting in your app so that user can change the settings of your app from iphone settings. If you are interested in this feature you can refer [Apple doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html)