# Detect LED Flash for Alerts setting status in code

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I detect "LED Flash for Alerts" (from Settings) status in code? I have tried:

```
AVCaptureDevice *torched=[AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];   

BOOL test = torched.torchMode;
BOOL test1 = torched.flashMode;
```

But it seams that it is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
BOOL test=NO;
BOOL test1=NO;

Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){
       if(device.flashMode==AVCaptureFlashModeOn)
          NSLog(@"ON");
       else
          NSLog(@"OFF");
    }
}
```

Hope it will helps you....

Comment: No, it always return NO but in Settings there is LED Flash for Alerts  - ON

Comment: it is still not  working. Also I have found an answer on stack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162386/programmatically-read-iphone-settings