# Launching settings app from custom iOS application

Tags: ios, settings

Is there any way to launch the build-in iOS  ***settings*** application from our custom applications.

Based on the URL schema , it is possible to launch safari,maps,YouTube,iTunes... etc. But in the documentation there is no any info related with ***settings*** app.

TIA.
-Balaji R.

Answer (score 7):

```
//code for opening settings app in iOS 8
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL  URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];


//code for opening settings App in ios5
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

No you can not. [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: You can in iOS 5.0, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app/7779240#7779240)