# How to jump to system settings on iOS?

Tags: ios

If my app detects that the network is disabled, I want to jump to the system network settings. How can I do this in iOS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Why not pick a username and stay awhile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no documented public APIs allowing you to do this. You *can* however use Apple's private frameworks, but you won't get an app accepted on the app store this way. It can, however, be used for Ad Hoc distribution and even Cydia for jailbroken apps.

[Here's](http://aralbalkan.com/2106) a quick way to get started with the private frameworks.

Comment: You can now do this in iOS 5.0, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app/7779240#7779240)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this with the current version of the API, and Apple specifically disallows this in their HIG. Presumably this means that if you find a way, your app will be rejected.