# How do you jump into Application Preference Setting Page with UIButton?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button, preference, setting

Does anyone know how to jump into application preference setting page without pressing home button?

How do I do it with UIBUTTON and get into application preference?

Comment: This was allowed in iOS five, then disallowed in either 5.0.1 or 5.1 I can't remember exactly which, but you can no longer do this.

Comment: Please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com/) is an alternative that might suit your needs.