# How can I launch the Settings app from AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiapplication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

I am calling:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"]];
```

But it isn't launching anything. I'd like to launch the Settings app and go to the WI-FI section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible.

[Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

These are the all the link pattern you can do in iOS 5 and above

Each article in this document describes the format of a particular type of URL:

[“Mail Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007892-SW1) describes the format for sending email with the Mail application.

[“Phone Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MailLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007892-SW1) describes the format for dialing phone numbers in the Phone application.

[“Text Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1) describes the format for launching the Messages application.

[“Map Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007894-SW1) describes the format for specifying locations in the Maps application.

[“YouTube Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/YouTubeLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007895-SW1) describes the format for linking to YouTube videos.

[“iTunes Links”](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/iTunesLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007896-SW1) describes the format for linking to items in the iTunes Music Store.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. In earlier iOS versions there was a url pattern that worked but Apple disabled that in iOS 5.

Comment: I think it first appeared in 5.0 and was removed in 5.0.1