# Any way to open the Settings application from my application in IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do I open the Settings application from my application?
Apple remove API for OS5.1 and later.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

make search before posting questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the settings for IOS version 5.1 and later. One best way you can do to overcome this is to prompt the user to change the settings through **UIAlertView**.