# Change wifi connection from xcode on Ipad

Tags: objective-c

I am new to ipad app development, is it feasible that i can change switch from WiFi to 3G or to another WiFi from xcode on Ipad.
If not switching then atleast launching Settings for Internet on Ipad with all configurations preset is possible ?

Comment: Hi This is the best possible i found for your situation  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: What I understand is, you want to change the settings of iPad from your application. If user have switched to WiFi then you want it to off and start on 3G! right?