# IOS CLLocationManager redirect to settings/preferences

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

this is my very first question on stack overflow. 
I want my apps able to redirect user to the settings/preferences. I'm studies a lot in stack overflow and most of the answer is "This only worked in iOS 5, won't work on IOS 5.1 or onwards anymore".
I knew this is very old question but still i'm very curious how is the Google Map API archive it?

I'm using IOS 6.1 Simulator and when i turn off the Location Service, Google Map API was able to prompt a message like below

"Turn On Location Services To Allow "app" to Determine Your Location", "Settings" button & "Cancel" button.

After I clicked on the "Settings" button, it will redirect to "Location Services"

I'm sorry because i don't have at least 10 reputation to post the printscreen.

Comment: Check comments of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: Thanks!! seems like it's not going to happen :(

Answer (score 0):

Try following code inside the action where you want to redirect to your **application settings**

```
NSURL *appSettings = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appSettings];
```

*(Working properly iOS 7 and above and by the time I'm posting this answer, we are having iOS 8.)*