# How to show alert to activate cellullar data iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

How to check in my iOS app if my cellullar data are turned off, and show this alert to navigate to it on settings and turn it on.

For example check the image!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple has some sample code available named Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) which you can use to see if the Internet is available.

If WiFi is down, you can bring up your own "You can turn on cellular data for this app" UIAlertView.

Comment: I know about rechability, I have used it in my project but I dont know how to show that alert view which sends me to settings and cellullar data. I mean what kind of method should I use to go to settings?

Comment: You might not be able to go directly to the settings from your own app. [See this related question about getting into Settings from your own app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app).

Comment: So this means that I can not go to settings in later versions than 5.0? That means apple has integrated only on safari that kind of algorithm?

Comment: Safari is Apple's own app, so they can do what they want. Everybody else only gets to do what is allowed per the guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Well, iOS 5.1 removed the ability to open Settings, so basically **you can't do it in iOS >= 5.1**

for **iOS < 5.1** was something like that

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=General&path=Network"]]
```