# present settings child view modally

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, settings.bundle

If presenting child settings view in settings bundle ***modally*** possible, how it can be achieved?
I have looked at Apple Documentation "Preferences and Settings Programming Guide", but found only a description of how to push it onto navigation stack.

Basically, I am trying to achieve the same popup view as in Facebook settings bundle below. Or is it a part of Apple's private API?

[image]

Comment: It's part of private API :(

Comment: If you planning to show Apple's settings screen, it is not possible.Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Comment: that is what i thought :/ but thanks anyway for your time