# Can I link from a web page to the 'Settings' app so a user is prompted to upgrade their OS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I have a web app that requires a supported version of Mobile Safari.

I know how to detect mobile safari, but **how can I make a link so the user visits the Settings app and is asked to update iOS**?

Comment: nohow, it's not secure to open user settings.

Comment: @Pinal I'm not asking to change the user settings, merely to open the Settings app. The user would still make changes. This is exactly how it would work with an Objective C/Swift app.

Answer (score -1):

iOS 8 is possible now, but prior iOS 8 can not.

Check follow link.

[Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: That is via Objective C, not via HTML/JavaScript.