# Is Apple app reject my app if my app redirected to settings page?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

If my app have a button and it will redirected to the iPhone settings page then is apple reject my app from review ?

if any one have answer or any apple support link which have written this rejection reason then please provide me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because only Apple knows what it will or will not reject.

Comment: @AshishThakkar is the situation cleared up for or do you need more info? otherwise don't forget to mark an answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No , there have no restriction if it's running iOS 8 and above -

```
- (void)openSettings
{
  if ( SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0") ) {

    BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
    if (canOpenSettings) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Can we confirm the answer for latest version. Because one of my friend's app got rejected due to this and it was targeted at ios 10 and above.

Answer (score 1):

No you will not get rejecte ford doing so! Keep in mind that deep linking into the settings is only possible since iOS 8, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's fine. [Here's how to do it.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS8.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014205-SW13)