# How to open device settings app not the app settings programmatically in iOS 8.0+

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8

I am working on an app in which I need to open the device settings app on button client rather than app settings. I am using UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString - but this opens the app settings page not the root level for device settings.

So, may I please get some suggestions on how to open the device settings app and may I also know is there any possibility to open the wi-fi settings page in the device settings programmatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Answer (score 1):

You con only open the app-settings as you mentioned above. 
If it would would it would also be listed in the documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Settings_Launch_URL

Even Apps like GoPro or Twitter just give instructions how to enter the settings rather then linking directly.