# going to settings programmatically from local notification iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift2, uilocalnotification

I wanna go to settings if the user clicks on "go to settings", can someone please help?

[heres what the notification looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCRl3.png)

Comment: Please don't use images for code, instead paste the code into your question.

Comment: You can [edit] your post. When you paste the code, make sure to select it and press Ctrl+K to format it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: im sorry bro im new to this, wont happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
      UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appSettings)
  }
```