# Cant open location services screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cllocationmanager, cllocation

please someone help me. How can I open Location Services from my app?  I tried this but it doesn't work

```
URL(string: "prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES")
```

Comment: Try to look to answers to this post: [How to open Location services screen from setting screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37654132/how-to-open-location-services-screen-from-setting-screen) You're probably trying to implement second most rated answer but you forgot to set *URL Schemes*. But note using this may cause that your app will be rejected.

Comment: Read "may cause rejection" as "you're almost guaranteed to be rejected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a specific sub-screen of Settings programatically no longer works, since iOS 11. Now all you can do is open main screen of Settings App, using url string `App-Prefs`

Comment: Using `App-Prefs` altogether is discouraged. With official settings url `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`, you should open the settings screen.