# Open Settings App from another App in iOS - React Native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm going through the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html) in React Native and can only find navigating to external links from the app I am in.

I want to be able to navigate to the `Settings` app (more specifically to the privacy > location services page) but, can not seem to find the necessary information on it. There is the [native iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app) way of doing it which I am trying to replicate through React Native.

Is this possible?

I have tried the following to detect if there is a Settings URL. The console logs that the `Settings url works` however, it does not navigate to that page.

Update: thanks to @zvona I am now navigating to the settings page but not sure how to get to a specific deep link.

```
Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:').then(supported => {
            
    console.log(`Settings url works`)
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:'
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(`An error has occured: ${error}`)
})
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can access settings of the application with:
`Linking.openURL('app-settings:');`

But I don't know (yet) how to open a specific deep-link.

2021 update use:

`Linking.openSettings();`

otherwise your app will be rejected due use of non-public URL scheme

Comment: This navigated to the location page that I needed (which was right at the location access surprisingly). Perhaps iOS is smart enough to know that I am requesting the location based on other areas of my code.

Comment: How did you find out which url the settings page was from? I could not find it in the docs

Comment: I'm poor with native code, but I just added `NSLog(UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString);` (which I saw in the answer you linked) to Appdelegate.m and output was `app-settings:` :)

Comment: what about for android?

Comment: @SibeliusSeraphini https://github.com/lunarmayor/react-native-open-settings

Comment: The API has changed for iOS, it should be like this: `Linking.openURL("App-Prefs:root=WIFI");`
For Android, this looks like the most comprehensive package: https://github.com/rmrs/react-native-settings

Comment: I wrote a quick snack for this a while ago: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/open-app-settings. It also relies on 3rd party lib **react-native-settings** on Android side.

Comment: beware your app could get rejected for using private apis: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50167923/3499115

Comment: I figured out how to open deeper. In my case I needed to open location settings, so I used: Linking.openURL('app-settings:Settings:Privacy')

Answer (score 14):

I successfully opened the settings by the code below, hope it's helpful :)

```
Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:').then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle settings url');
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

Reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native//docs/linking.html

Answer (score 12):

Since React Native version 0.59 this should be possible using `openSettings();`. This is described in the React Native [Linking documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/linking#opensettings). Although it did not work for me. When I tried quickly I saw a `_reactNative.Linking.openSettings is not a function` error message.

```js
Linking.openSettings();
```

Comment: Looks like the documentation might be out of sync with the code on this one. I see it in the code for 0.60, but not any of the 0.59 releases:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/v0.60.0/Libraries/Linking/Linking.js

Comment: Note that this works only for apps using native code, not those using expo-cli. See warning at the top of https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking.html

Answer (score 7):

You can deep-link referencing the settings's index like so:

```
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:{index}')
```

For example `Linking.openURL('app-settings:{3}')` would open the Bluetooth settings.

Comment: Not working on iOS10.3.3 + React Native 0.44.3, index=3 ( and other index such as 1, 2, 3...) will jump to Cellular data...

Comment: For iOS 14 you can call `Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Bluetooth')` to open Bluetooth Settings

Comment: how to deep link to location peripheral settings in iOS ?

Answer (score 5):

Linking.openURL('app-settings:1');

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer that worked for me and is easy to apply.

[openSettings](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-permissions#opensettings) function in @react-native-community/react-native-permissions works for both iOS and Android.

Calling openSettings function will direct the user to the settings page of your app.

```
import { openSettings } from 'react-native-permissions';
openSettings();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can import Linking from 'react-native' and then use Linking.openSettings() to trigger the call. This link explains it very concisely:

https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/eyegh79kqs-how-to-open-the-settings-app-in-reactnative-060

Comment: Updated, explained a bit more

Answer (score 1):

For example: to navigate under Settings/Bluetooth you have to use `Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Bluetooth');`

For iOS 14 and ReactNative 16.13

Comment: As of the end of 2020, no React Native 16.13 version exists

Answer (score 1):

You can use the most easiest way to open the app setting from react-native.
just,
**import { Linking } from 'react-native';**
and user below line anywhere you want open the app setting.
**Linking.openSettings();**

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this didn't work for me on Android and I found something that did. Hope this helps anyone looking for the same. :)

https://github.com/lunarmayor/react-native-open-settings 
I don't have the ability to test it for iOS though.

Opens the platform specific settings for the given application.

Comment: hey guys is it possible to open the mobile setting page from external web url too tried to search but didnt found anything...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle your case using Linking from react-native. In my case, I accessed the touch id settings on IOS using:-

```
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:PASSCODE');
```