# Open Android System Settings in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39082202/6272893) but it didn't work with Android.

How can I open Settings with `Linking.openURL('setting-url-here')`

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41677735/react-native-unable-to-open-device-settings-from-my-android-app

Answer (score 2):

Linking.openSettings()

Better late than never. For more info.

Stack overflow question and answer: [React Native Open settings through Linking.openURL in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582694/react-native-open-settings-through-linking-openurl-in-ios)

ReactNative Docs:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#open-custom-settings

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library `react-native-common-intents`
[React-native-Common-intents](https://github.com/wahdatjan/react-native-common-intents)

to open settings you can call

```
RNIntents.openSettings();
```