# React-Native: Unable to open device settings from my android app

Tags: react-native

I'm using React-Native (^0.35.0) for making Android application. There is scenario where I need to check whether internet connectivity is present or not. If there is no internet connectivity then I need show a button which will open device settings (through which user can enable his connectivity).

I'm Using **Linking** library provided by react-native.

I am trying in followin way:

```
componentWillMount(){
    Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:')
      .then(supported => {
        if (!supported) {
          console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
       } else {
       return Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
      }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
}
```

then above code gives- console **Can't handle url:app-settings:**

When I tried following:

```
componentWillMount(){
    Linking.canOpenURL('app-settings:')
      .then(supported => {
        return Linking.openURL('app-settings:');
      }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
    }
```

Above code gives- **Error: Could not open URL 'app-settings:': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=app-settings: flg=0x10000000 }**

Is there anything that I am missing here? or Is there is need to change in any other file like **AndroidMainfest.xml**, **MainActivity.java**, etc..

Comment: this has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39229693/515114

Comment: @funkysoul: Not cleared in above link where should I exactly add that **Native Code** which you mentioned in above link. and How to integrate it in my component?

Comment: you need to write native code that can be called through the react native module. this module might help you in a way (only android) https://github.com/javorosas/react-native-open-wifi

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used the same steps for opening device network operator settings. The steps above are quite helpful.

**Here is my code.**

```
package com.<projectname>.opensettings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;

public class OpenSettingsModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    /**
     * return the string name of the NativeModule which represents this class in JavaScript
     * In JS access this module through React.NativeModules.OpenSettings
     */
    return "OpenSettings";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void openNetworkSettings(Callback cb) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

    if (currentActivity == null) {
      cb.invoke(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      currentActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
      cb.invoke(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      cb.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
  }


  /*This is for open location Settings*/
  @ReactMethod
  public void openLocationSettings(Callback cb) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

    if (currentActivity == null) {
      cb.invoke(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      currentActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS));
      cb.invoke(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      cb.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /* constructor */
  public OpenSettingsModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }
}
```

All you need to do is just put the constant(like ACTION_NETWORK_OPERATOR_SETTINGS) in above code and create your own function like one which is created above i.e. openNetworkSettings. Other steps 4, 5 and 6 are same.

**Here are the list of constants:**
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Answer (score 26):

I'm new with react-native and not having much insights of java(android). I faced similar problem but I managed to open Android settings by creating the custom react-native module.

Below are the steps which I've taken to achieve this functionality.

**1** - Create a folder for module under `android/app/src/main/java/com/<projectname>/`. In this case I've created the `opensettings` folder.

**2** - Under this folder create module file `OpenSettingsModule.java` (where we put module functionality) and package file `OpenSettingsPackage.java` (where we will register our module).

**3** - Put following code in `OpenSettingsModule.java`

```
package com.<projectname>.opensettings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;

public class OpenSettingsModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    /**
     * return the string name of the NativeModule which represents this class in JavaScript
     * In JS access this module through React.NativeModules.OpenSettings
     */
    return "OpenSettings";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void openNetworkSettings(Callback cb) {
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

    if (currentActivity == null) {
      cb.invoke(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      currentActivity.startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS));
      cb.invoke(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      cb.invoke(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  /* constructor */
  public OpenSettingsModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
  }
}
```

**4** - We have done with our module which will open android settings by calling `openNetworkSettings` function. Now we need to register this module. Add below code in `OpenSettingsPackage.java`

```
package com.<projectname>.opensettings;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class OpenSettingsPackage implements ReactPackage {
  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

    modules.add(new OpenSettingsModule(reactContext));

    return modules;
  }

  @Override
  public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

**5** - Provide this package to `getPackages` method of the `MainApplication.java`.

```
import com.<projectname>.opensettings.*;
...
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new OpenSettingsPackage() /* <---- add here */
  );
}
```

**6** - We are done with JAVA part, import `NativeModules` in your component, we can now access our module through `NativeModules.OpenSettings`. JSX implementation as below.

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'; 

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openSettings = this.openSettings.bind(this);
  }

  openSettings() {
    NativeModules.OpenSettings.openNetworkSettings(data => {
      console.log('call back data', data);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={this.openSettings}>Open Android Settings</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**7** - reference

https://shift.infinite.red/native-modules-for-react-native-android-ac05dbda800d#.yj9pspfpn
http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Note: If there is any better way to achieve the same functionality then please let me know here.

Comment: I've noticed when I was running that, the compiler would return **OpenSettingsPackage.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype** where I ended up removing the @Override.

Comment: I am getting this error:- TypeError: Cannot read property 'openNetworkSettings' of undefined

Comment: Please remove  *@Override* if you are getting error **OpenSettingsPackage.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype**