# React Native Open settings through Linking.openURL in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to open ios setting app from my app. the settings destination is [ settings => notification => myapp ]. to turn on & turn off push notification.

There are some documents about how to link to settings, but I don't know how to open deep link. (notification => myapp).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can deep-link referencing the settings's index like so:

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
```

Above method only for IOS

Comment: Thanks. I can do it with  `Linking.openURL('app-settings://notification/myapp')}`

Comment: Is there any solution for android which does not require an external lib?

Comment: @Arunkumar Do you know the equivalent for Android?

Comment: @wcandillon sry I don't know, I'll check and let you know

Answer (score 42):

Since React Native 0.60 to open App settings use:

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

Linking.openSettings();
```

Open the app’s custom settings, if it has any.

Works for Android and iOS

Docs link:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#opensettings

Comment: is there way to open the Location permistion setting directly?

Comment: try this `Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:LOCATION_SERVICES')`

Comment: I got this error `Could not open URL 'App-Prefs:LOCATION_SERVICES': No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=app-prefs:LOCATION_SERVICES flg=0x10000000 }`

Comment: Ah sorry this is for ios. For android i use this library 'react-native-settings'

Comment: This did not work for me

Comment: @TusharShahi verify your code again, here is the docs for it: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#opensettings

Answer (score 6):

for iOS 14, this is how i open location service settings

```
Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:Privacy&path=LOCATION')
```

tested in react native 0.63.4

Answer (score 5):

Use `Linking.openURL`. For example, below is how to check and open Health app on iOS

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native'

async goToSettings() {
  const healthAppUrl = 'x-apple-health://'
  const canOpenHealthApp = await Linking.canOpenURL(healthAppUrl)
  if (canOpenHealthApp) {
    Linking.openURL(healthAppUrl)
  } else {
    Linking.openURL('app-settings:')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To access specific settings screens, try this:

`Linking.openURL("App-Prefs:root=WIFI");`

Linking to `app-settings` only opens the settings for the 
Reference: [iOS Launching Settings -> Restrictions URL Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8246070/ios-launching-settings-restrictions-url-scheme) (note that `prefs` changed to `App-Prefs` in iOS 6)

Comment: has anyone else tried this? unfortunately it did not work for me on iOS 11 (both simulator and real device)

Comment: Hey, thanks in my case 'App-Prefs:root' works for me

Comment: as of iOS 14, what's working for me is Linking.openURL("App-prefs:General") - just remove `root=` from examples that have it

Comment: Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:ACCESSIBILITY'); is working. for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for Open Specific System URL - `Linking.openURL('App-Prefs:{3}')`

Answer (score 0):

Worked for iOS 16.6

```
  //Only iOS
  // Will navigate to Settings app 
  Linking.openURL('App-prefs:root');
  //Will navigate to Settings app to WiFi settings
  Linking.openURL('App-prefs:WIFI');
  //Will navigate to Settings of your app (
  Linking.openURL('app-settings:');

  //iOS and Android
  // Will navigate to Settings of your app 
  Linking.openSettings();
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
Linking.openURL('app-settings://notification/myapp')
```

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work :(