# react native check if location services are on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, geolocation

I'm using navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() in react native and it's working fine.
But i would like to be able to react nicely if location services are turned off (a dialog box that leads the user to settings).
I found that plugin for android and i think it's going to work fine :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-android-location-services-dialog-box 
How should i do in iOS ?

Answer (score -1):

### EDIT

You can use this very well done 3rd party [library](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location)

and then use it like this :

```
Location.getAuthorizationStatus((authorization) => {
  console.log(authorization)
});
```

### Previous answer

`getCurrentPosition` can take an error callback. This will be triggered if the location is not enabled.

You can do something like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({ position });
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(alert);
  },
  {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000}
);
```

You can check the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html) for more informations.

Comment: thank you, i checked that but the error does not seam to return a clear error code that allows to determine the source of the error...

Comment: In addition to that, this doesn't help openning OS parameters

Comment: To open the settings in ios, you can use : `Linking.openURL('app-settings:')`. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39081688/open-settings-app-from-another-app-in-ios-react-native)

Comment: @alexandre you can also us the library I added in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, cool thanks ! And do you have any idea how to sort error types ? like error because, location is not authorized for your app, error because location is off, error because couldn't retrive location, error timeout...

Comment: You have a list of status [here](https://github.com/timfpark/react-native-location#locationgetauthorizationstatus) that already gives you some info on the reason you could not get the location. It's all the info you'll get I fear.