# Programmatically stop app upgrade in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Manually we can turn off app auto update option through iPhone setting. Is there any possibility to disable app upgrade option programmatically through my iPhone application ? Please share some information, if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope, apps can't change user preferences.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you prevent a user from updating your app?

Answer (score 1):

IF you mean to programmatically stop an upgrade by toggling the switch that the user has set on their iOS device settings, then the answer is NO WAY - app runs on limited rights, check out ['App Security - Sandboxing'](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec15bfe098e/web).
The most an app can do in relation to Device Settings, is to [open the appropriate Device Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5655727/6612762) for the End User and ask them to make the changes.

It really depends what your business reason is for wanting to stop an upgrade? I'm curious to know.

There is no official API for stopping/pausing upgrades or any events fired by iOS to the app that an upgrade's about to take place.

In my experience, app Upgrades are a common issue with **offline-first apps**, where you may have local data that hasn't synced with upstream yet - and an upgrade would wipe it out.
In that case, you either implement a Migration script that runs on App Launch and performs migration.
Or another way is to listen periodically for new app releases via say ['Background Fetch'](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh)
checking with either the 'App Store release api' (e.g. using [Siren](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren)) or your own server, and sync the data before the upgrade takes place - once Upgrade take place, restore data from upstream.

Hope this helps somehow.