# show option to change to airplane mode in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks, iphone-privateapi, airplane-mode

I heard that apple prevent from programmers to toggle airplane mode on and off, there is option to pop up message to the user then he will decide what he want to do? if yes how could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if there is a network connection, if there is none
2. Present the user with an alert with options such as Cancel and Open Settings, if the user chooses to open the settings app
3. Navigate to Settings app. See this to see how to open Settings app from your app: [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)