# Opening app's notification settings in the settings app

Tags: ios, swift, application-settings

In the case that a user may accidentally declines to receive notifications and wants to turn notifications later, how can I use an NSURL to open the IOS Settings App to my app's notification page where they can select Allow Notifications?

Comment: `UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening the Settings app from another app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

Comment: @Matt did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

**Updated 8 Dec, 2021:**

This method will open Settings > Your App. It will show all available privacy toggles like camera, photos, notifications, cellular data, etc.

After a comment from @Mischa below, tested and updated the answer to this (more succinct):

```
if let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
}
```

**Previous answer:**

I found the answer to this question (albeit helpful) has a bit too much assumed logic. Here is a plain and simple Swift 5 implementation if anyone else stumbles upon this question:

```
if let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier, let appSettings = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString + bundleIdentifier) {
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Most succinct answer I have seen to achieve this

Comment: This opens the app settings, but not the app notification settings. I wonder if there's an Apple approved way to do that.

Comment: @SudoPlz No, there is no (public) way to access subpages of your app's settings page. But your users will understand as they immediately see the "Notifications" option on the main page.

Comment: I wonder why this answer appends the `bundleIdentifier` to the actual settings URL. Is there an actual reason for that? The URL created from `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` opens the app settings as well and it seems obsolete. In other words: The simplest solution is [Eric Yuan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68170742/2062785). Apple's documentation of the property states the same: _"When you open the URL built from this string, the system launches the Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any. Use this string with `open(_:options:completionHandler:)`."_

Comment: Mischa, you are probably right, it might have been the case that back when I wrote this answer it needed the bundle identifier, but possibly not anymore. I'll give it a check in a moment and update my answer if that's the case. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 27):

For Swift 3, use `UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString` to go to settings for your app where it shows the Notifications status and "Cellular Data"

```
let settingsButton = NSLocalizedString("Settings", comment: "")
let cancelButton = NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: "")
let message = NSLocalizedString("Your need to give a permission from notification settings.", comment: "")
let goToSettingsAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

goToSettingsAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: settingsButton, style: .destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
            return
        }

        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(settingsUrl as URL)
            } 
        }
    }
}))

logoutUserAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: cancelButton, style: .cancel, handler: nil))
```

Comment: It opens Setting's page. But the question is asking for App's notification's page.

Comment: @ChanchalRaj, yea there is no way to do that. Settings is close as you are going to get.

Comment: In Swift 4 this has become `UIApplication.openSettingsURLString`.

Answer (score 10):

Swift 5:

```
if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

This should keep you covered for all iOS versions, including iOS 15 and iOS 16.

```swift
extension UIApplication {
  private static let notificationSettingsURLString: String? = {
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
      return UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString
    }

    if #available(iOS 15.4, *) {
      return UIApplicationOpenNotificationSettingsURLString
    }

    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
      // just opens settings
      return UIApplication.openSettingsURLString
    }

    // lol bruh
    return nil
  }()

  private static let appNotificationSettingsURL = URL(
    string: notificationSettingsURLString ?? ""
  )

  func openAppNotificationSettings() -> Bool {
    guard
      let url = UIApplication.appNotificationSettingsURL,
      self.canOpen(url) else { return false }
    return self.open(url)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```swift
Button {
  let opened = UIApplication.shared.openAppNotificationSettings()
  if !opened {
    print("lol fail")
  }
} label: {
  Text("Notifications")
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Should be the new accepted answer!

Comment: this does not work on iOS 16.0 simulator

Comment: This is working in iOS 16.4 simulator for me, but it's not working in an iOS 17.2 simulator (it is working on a physical iOS 17.2 device though). Any ideas here? Want to make sure it'll work in production.

Answer (score 5):

Since iOS 15.4 we can deeplink to the notif settings screen directly using `UIApplicationOpenNotificationSettingsURLString`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopennotificationsettingsurlstring?language=objc

Comment: For 16.0 they replaced it with `openNotificationSettingsURLString`

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** This will be rejected by Apple.

To open notifications part of settings use this

```
UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=NOTIFICATIONS_ID")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Comment: This will be rejected by Apple: "Your app uses the "prefs:root=" non-public URL scheme, which is a private entity. The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change."

Comment: @nurider We've had an app in the App Store for 2 years which uses "prefs:root="

Comment: This just brings me to my app's settings page; not the notifications page. Does this still work for you? For me it's the same as using UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString. iOS 12.something, Xcode 10.something.

Comment: @DarrenBlack Correct I don't believe this is possible anymore on iOS 12.

Comment: @ttorbik Oh but it should be! ;)