# iOS - Opening App Push Notification Settings screen from App

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to open `Push Notification Settings` from my app. Is it possible in iOS? I know I can open `Settings` screen only.

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 15.4 we can deeplink to the notif settings screen directly:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopennotificationsettingsurlstring?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

There is no official way to so do.
You can navigate directly to the Notification Setting page but doing so can cause your app to be rejected.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49041704/3867033

Comment: any official documentation reference?? I wanted to read it if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can open app setting from your app. Refer this apple doc

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 16 you should be able to do this

```swift
if let url = URL(string: UIApplication.openNotificationSettingsURLString) {
    // Ask the system to open that URL.
    await UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/4013180-opennotificationsettingsurlstrin