# Open contacts app from react-native app and get the selected contact info

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to open contacts app in IOS from a react-native app that I am developing. Also, I want to get the list of contacts which the user selects. Is there any way to do it in react native?

I went through this stack overflow link: [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app) and learnt that we could do it in IOS by using **URL schemes**. I searched google for URL scheme of Contacts app but couldn't find one. Even if I find one, how to get a callback ?

I have implemented **react-native-contacts** library to get list of contacts. But I would rather like my users to navigate to contacts app and select contacts. Can we do it in react-native ?

Comment: Do you get any answer for this