# Open your app's settings iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Quite similar question but not really the same question: [Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)
That question is about the **Settings** application of the iOS and not about opening your project's settings on your phone.

Now, in iOS 10.x, it works for me:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root")!) {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root")!)
} else {
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"prefs:root")!)
}
```

But then again, this code merely opens up your **Settings** and not your app's settings. I know it's 100% possible because I have tried it on the app called **Foursquare**. If you give **NEVER** to **Foursquare's Location Settings**, it will generate an alert which can redirect you to its own settings in the **Settings** app.

This is exactly what I need to do. I've been reading several questions for now, but I believe I couldn't find any similar questions to mine.

Also, I have already tried adding my app name to the URL string, like so, but didn't work:

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=MY_APP_NAME")!)
```

Comment: Take a look into: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5655727/6595536

Comment: Yep, it's really the answer. Weird, I believe I have tried that last night, but now it's working. Thanks. Also, should I delete this question?