# iOS 11 Bluetooth URL Scheme

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios11

So recently we started testing our app on iOS11 and noticed that we were no longer able to navigate the user to the bluetooth settings page to prompt them to turn it on. I was wondering if anyone had figured out what the new URL scheme was. `App-Prefs:root=Bluetooth` was working for all versions below iOS 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's no solution at this time(9/19/2017) for this issue on iOS 11.

The codes below using [UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopensettingsurlstring?language=objc) to open the Settings.app works on iOS 11. Maybe it's a workaround at this time for you.

> When you open the URL built from this string, the system launches the Settings app and displays the app’s custom settings, if it has any.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

The code snippet in C#：

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(new NSUrl(UIApplication.OpenSettingsUrlString));
```

References:

- [Anyone have anything on URL Schemes in iOS 11 developer Beta?](https://www.reddit.com/r/workflow/comments/6p9fbw/anyone_have_anything_on_url_schemes_in_ios_11/?sort=new)
- [How to open Location Services from iOS application for iOS 11 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051072/5474400)
- [Using App-Prefs:root=](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/75110)