# Apps Not Showing in Settings on iPhone in iOS 15.4 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, settings, ios-15.4

I recently developed an iOS app using Xcode 13.1 . I ran it on my iPhone (which is currently operating on iOS 15.4), and it worked fine.

However, my app uses the location, and I have been attempting to have the user go to settings, and enable/disable the location permission.

But my app does not appear in the list of apps in settings. It does not show up in the developer section either. I did multiple things (reboot all settings - restart my iPhone...) but nothing helped.

**Info.Plist Permission:-**

[image: Screenshot]

**Permission Popup:-**

[image: Screenshot]

How can I resolve this bug? Thanks.

Already Tried Given below Answer but no luck:-

[Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app)

[How to open your app in Settings iOS 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46421646/how-to-open-your-app-in-settings-ios-11)

[How to open Settings programmatically like in Facebook app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23824054/how-to-open-settings-programmatically-like-in-facebook-app)

[How to open your app's settings (inside the Settings app) with Swift (iOS 11)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49363516/how-to-open-your-apps-settings-inside-the-settings-app-with-swift-ios-11)

[How do I open phone settings when a button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28152526/how-do-i-open-phone-settings-when-a-button-is-clicked)

Comment: Are you using simulator or iPhone device?

Comment: iPhone device XR(15.4)

Comment: I think you are not trying to get the location. Just on any button, try to open camera (UIImagePickerController). Your app will appear in the setting.

Comment: ok let me check and will update you shortly.

Comment: @AsifHabib It's working with camera permission, but if I uninstall the app and again install the app without camera permission,  same issue occurs, Apps Not Showing in Settings screen.

Comment: @AsifHabib, Please check updated question.

Comment: With Camera permissions, location permissions were shown or not?

Comment: @AsifHabib sorry for late reply, no with location permissions not shown app in the setting screen.

Comment: Then try some sample from github that you are sure works. Try switching the iPhone device. Hopefully you will find the issue.

Comment: @AsifHabib i already tried with multiple devices. I have tested in iphone 6s(14.5) not shown and it's only shown in iphone 6plus(12.5.5).

Comment: @ShamDhiman did u get any solution for the posted question? facing the same issue, this happens only with location permission

Comment: @SubhangiPawar, No i didn't get any solution for this. Sorry for late reply. Please try with the latest iOS.   :(