# How to open device setting for iOS8?

Tags: ios, swift3, settings

I keep seeing that you can use

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
        print("Settings opened: \(success)")
    })
}
```

but it only works for iOS 10 and above. But how can I do the same thing for iOS 8?

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app

Answer (score 0):

`UIApplication.openSettingsURLString` will return settings url string.

```
if let settingsURL = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(settingsURL, completionHandler: { (success) in
        print("Settings opened: \(success)")
    })
}
```

Comment: open(_:options:completionHandler:) is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I rarely see any application support for iOS 8 anymore. But if you want to know, here is the answer:

```
let urlStr = "yourURL"
if let linkURL = URL(string: urlString), UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL) {
 UIApplication.shared.openURL(linkURL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

```
if UIApplication.openSettingsURLString != nil{
    if let aString = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString){
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(aString)
    }
}
```