# IOS Localization

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I'm implementing app localization through phone system preferences, i follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app) thread, but faced an issue, when i back to my app from system preferences, app is not responding to any actions ? what i'm doing wrong or what i should implement to fix this bug.

my code:

```
Button(action: {
    if let url = NSURL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString) as URL? {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    }
        }) {
    SelectLanguageButton(title: "login_view_language_btn_lbl".localized)
}
```

localization ext:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return AppLocalization.language(key: self)
    }
    
    func localizedWithParams(_ arguments: CVarArg...) -> String {
        return AppLocalization.language(key: self, arguments)
    }
}
```

Also i tried this way:
`NSLocalizedString("login_view_email_textfield_lbl", comment: "")`

But way of localization is not the point for me.