# I want to open the iPhone Settings screen's 'Screen Time' page inside my app in a pop-up window on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

1. I want to open iPhone Settings Screen time page inside my iOS App.
2. When I try to open the 'Screen Time' settings, it takes me to the iPhone's settings screen instead of opening it within my app itself.

I have followed below code -

```
if let url = URL(string: "App-Prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME") {

        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}
```

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

you need to implement this

```
Screen Time

Screen Time: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME
Screen Time ⇾ Downtime: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=DOWNTIME
Screen Time ⇾ App Limits: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=APP_LIMITS
Screen Time ⇾ Always Allowed: prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=ALWAYS_ALLOWED
```

plz check this link ([Opening the Settings app from another app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655674/opening-the-settings-app-from-another-app/35987082#35987082))

Comment: Can anyone provide code example? Seems not to work at my case: let url = URL(string: "prefs:root=SCREEN_TIME&path=DOWNTIME")!

Comment: what error you are facing @DaewizalForshizal

Comment: No error - just nothing happens. I've done some research, and currently it works like this: URL(string: "App-prefs:SCREEN_TIME"). Also needs to have URL scheme configured with "prefs". Tested on Xcode 15.2 and iOS 17.3

Comment: Update: Seems it does not even need URL type in the scheme. It worked without it.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on XCode 15.2 and iOS 17.3

Code snipped to launch "Screen Time" settings screen:

```
 if let appSettings = URL(string: "App-prefs:SCREEN_TIME"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appSettings) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(appSettings)
}
```

Comment: I believe that the original poster is asking to open the screen time settings without leaving their app, i.e., in a sheet or other overlay, so this won't do what they want.