# Could be open iPhone settings screen as a popup window inside 3rd party app on iOS

Tags: ios

We want to open an iPhone settings screen as a popup window inside my 3rd party app so that the user does not have to leave the app to view their iPhone settings page. Is that possible? I would not like the user to be redirected from the app to the settings page and then use the back button to return to the app. If additional consent may be needed from the user to do that, we are fine with that. Any guidance on how to do that?

Comment: It is not possible.  The only thing you can do is [open your app's own settings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623042-opensettingsurlstring/). By default iOS will put a button to return to your app at the top left of the screen.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667826/i-want-to-open-the-iphone-settings-screens-screen-time-page-inside-my-app-in).