# Switching from View 1 to Bluetooth settings..can't possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am facing problem in switching from view 1 to Bluetooth settings i.e in view 1 i have given 1 Button..on clicking on that button i want to switch to view 2(Bluetooth settings)..but it can't be possible in iPhone..since we can't access the default settings of iPhone..for that we have to create the application preferences..

Q.1 Is there any way to access the default settings of Bluetooth in iPhone?

Q.2 Is there any official link where it can be mention that we can't access the default settings?

I want suggestion..please help..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Apps cannot open the settings application to a specific screen. The reason that apps like MapMyFitness open preferences is because they ask for permission to use Bluetooth Low Energy. Asking for permission is managed by [CBCentralManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html) on first usage.

[image]

These popups are shown automatically by the system framework. The message can be customized using the `purpose` property for location services, that is not possible in case of Bluetooth.

No private API was used for this, so there's no reason for the app to be rejected.

Credit goes to this bellow SO question

[how some apps can open setting app programmatically within their app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587370/how-some-apps-can-open-setting-app-programmatically-within-their-app)

**que 2.**

At previous we are opening Setting Page from app Using Bellow line of Code:-

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

But now upto ios5.0 it was working after that this one depreciated. and Till now Apple not providing the URL Schema for achieving this one in newer versions.

**Links of similar question and it's Answer:-**

[Call the official *Settings* app from my app on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4496813/call-the-official-settings-app-from-my-app-on-iphone)

[iPhone- Open Settings from my application iOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682164/iphone-open-settings-from-my-application-ios-6)

[is it possible to open Settings App using openURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090373/is-it-possible-to-open-settings-app-using-openurl)

[Programmatically opening the settings app (iPhone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736047/programmatically-opening-the-settings-app-iphone)

[How can I open the Settings app when the user presses a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092162/how-can-i-open-the-settings-app-when-the-user-presses-a-button)

[iPhone: Opening Application Preferences Panel From App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113391/iphone-opening-application-preferences-panel-from-app)

[Open UIPickerView by clicking on an entry in the app's preferences - How to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127769/open-uipickerview-by-clicking-on-an-entry-in-the-apps-preferences-how-to)

[Open the Settings app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942974/open-settings-app)

Comment: Nitin Gohel thanks for reply.. can you give me the Ans. of my Q.2

Comment: i also given info about it and in stackOverflow you get lot's of similar question.

Comment: show this question to your client a attach links of similar  questions